# How to use devise-invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I just started with Rails and devise and I have a task, allow users to sign up only by invitation of existing user. I choose devise-invitable gem and got stuck with a bit unclear documentation. I have this code:

```
def invitationForm
    @nuser = User.new
end
def invite_user
  @user =  User.invite!({:email => @nuser.email}, current_user)
end
```

Where `invitationForm` renders a form:

```
<%= form_for @nuser, url: {action: "invite_user"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.submit "Invite" %>
<% end %>
```

After all I`m getting this error:

```
RuntimeError in User#invite

Showing //invite.html.erb where line #2 raised:

Could not find a valid mapping for nil
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your problems could be here:

```
<%= form_for @nuser, url: {action: "invite_user"} do |f| %>
```

Your form was pointing to `invite` instead of the `invite_user` method you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the deal was in the setup, somehow. After creating a new project and starting from scratch all workred fine.